# Reading Text in a Label From Different Application

Tags: vb.net, gettext, handle, hwnd

I have a application working in my pc.
I can get every detail of that application(handle,mainwindowhandle,etc.)

And that application has a lot of labels, and I want to read that label and msgbox that string in my own application.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (which [pinvoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.GetWindowText) has nicely covered):

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowText(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpString As StringBuilder, ByVal cch As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowTextLength(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
  Dim length As Integer = GetWindowTextLength(otherAppLabelHandle)
  Dim sb As New StringBuilder(length + 1)
  GetWindowText(otherAppLabelHandle, sb, sb.Capacity)
  MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString())
End Sub
```

Comment: And How i will get the handle of a label from an another application?

Comment: @sarkolata Your post said you have every detail of the application, including the handles.  What details do you have?

Comment: Ah sorry for my post, i see its misunderstandable.
I can get the mainwindowhandle, mainwindowtitle etc.
(all get properties from system.diagonistics.process class)
I already start the application from my vb.net program.